# How to use org-ref-export-to-html in org-publish-project?

Tags: org-mode, html, org-ref

I am trying to use `org-ref-export-to-html` from org-ref Version 3 as the `:publishing-function` of `org-publish-project-alist`.

Based on `org-html-publish-to-html` which I used to use with this function previously, I understood that I should use create a function that

1. receives `plist` `filename` `pub-dir` as arguments
2. generates the HTML file
3. returns an output file name.

This is my attempt.

```
(defun org-ref-publish-to-html (plist filename pub-dir)
  "Copied code snippets from `org-publish-org-to` and `org-export-output-file-name` in ox.el and ox-publish.el. Return output file name."
  (unless (or (not pub-dir) (file-exists-p pub-dir)) (make-directory pub-dir t))
  (let* ((org-inhibit-startup t)
     (work-buffer (find-file-noselect filename))
     (base-name (file-name-sans-extension filename))
     (output-file (concat
               (cond
            (pub-dir (concat (file-name-as-directory pub-dir)
                     (file-name-nondirectory base-name)))
            ((file-name-absolute-p base-name) base-name)
            (t base-name))
               ".html")))
    ;; generate html file
    (with-current-buffer work-buffer
      (org-ref-export-to-html))
    (kill-buffer work-buffer)
    ;; return output file name
    output-file))
```

However, I always get the error message: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` when I run `org-publish-project` with this as the publishing function.

Can anybody advise? Thanks

Comment: Do `C-h f org-ref-export-to-html` and see whether you are calling it correctly (I don't have `org-ref` installed so I cannot check for you). What arguments does it take? What does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. This allows the export to HTML with org-ref citations and a bibliography section at the bottom.

```
;; Very simplified version of org-ref-export-to from org-ref-export.el
;; that export to filename
(defun org-ref-export-to-file-nomarks-noopen
    (backend filename &optional async subtreep visible-only body-only info)  
    (org-export-with-buffer-copy
     (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
     (org-ref-process-buffer backend subtreep)
     (org-export-to-file backend filename
             async subtreep visible-only
             body-only info)
     ))

;; org-html-publish-to-html from ox-html.el adapted to org-ref
;; Instead of org-export-to-file calls org-ref-export-to-file-nomarks-noopen
(defun org-ref-html-publish-to-html (plist filename pub-dir)
  (unless (or (not pub-dir) (file-exists-p pub-dir)) (make-directory pub-dir t))
  ;; Check if a buffer visiting FILENAME is already open.
  (let* ((org-inhibit-startup t)
     (visiting (find-buffer-visiting filename))
     (work-buffer (or visiting (find-file-noselect filename))))
    (unwind-protect
      (with-current-buffer work-buffer
        (let ((output (org-export-output-file-name ".html" nil pub-dir)))
          (org-ref-export-to-file-nomarks-noopen 'html output
            nil nil nil (plist-get plist :body-only)
            (org-combine-plists
             plist
             `(:crossrefs
               ,(org-publish-cache-get-file-property
                 ;; Normalize file names in cache.
                 (file-truename filename) :crossrefs nil t)
               :filter-final-output
               (org-publish--store-crossrefs
                org-publish-collect-index
                ,@(plist-get plist :filter-final-output))))))))))
```

Afterwards, I replace the default `publishing-function`

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist `(
    ("notes"
     :publishing-function org-ref-html-publish-to-html
     ... *the rest* ...
     ))
```

I also put the bibliography at the bottom of my file to be exported

```
* Bibliography
[[bibliographystyle:plain]]
bibliography:~/notes/papers/refs.bib
```

Seems to work for these package versions, but I have not tested it extensively:

- org-ref version 3.0 (20230102.1658)
- emacs version 28.2 (build of 2022-09-12)